# Is discrimination based on job occupation legal in United States?

Tags: united-states

Recently some cops were asked to leave a coffee shop because other people didnt feel safe. In my country you can't deny service based on anything, as far as I know, they list a large number of reasons with ellipsis, one of the listed ones could be "social condition" for this case, which isnt the same as "economical status" which is also listed.

Some people argued that it was discrimination and others argued it wasnt because police men aren't a protected class. As far as I know, the  Civil Rights Act of 1964 protects against discrimination based in race, color, religion or sex. Does that mean discrimination based on job occupation is legal in United States?

Comment: Just a note that "it was discrimination" and "it wasn't illegal discrimination" are not in conflict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Discrimination is legal except on the basis of a [protected class](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_group)

> U.S. federal law protects individuals from discrimination or harassment based on the following nine protected classes: sex, race, age, disability, color, creed, national origin, religion, or genetic information

Absent from that list is “occupation”.

State law may add additional classes including sexual orientation and marital status. Private organisations are also free to add additional classes for their operations.